# semantic of performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

what I am having is

```
- (void)startTheBackgroundJob {   
    1.NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    2.[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
    3.[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    4.//[self makeMyProgressBarMoving];
    5.[pool release];

}

- (void)makeMyProgressBarMoving {

    float actual = [threadProgressView progress];
    threadValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", actual];
    if (actual < 1) {
        threadProgressView.progress = actual + 0.01;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
    else threadStartButton.hidden = NO;

}
```

At line number 4 of starTheBackgroundJob, you can set value of `waitUntilDone = YES` (or NO).

I read the reference and they indicate that :

> Wait
>
> A Boolean that specifies whether the current thread blocks until after
>   the specified selector is performed on the receiver on the main
>   thread. Specify YES to block this thread; otherwise, specify NO to
>   have this method return immediately.
>        If the current thread is also the main thread, and you specify YES for this parameter, the message is delivered and processed
>   immediately.

**My question is :**

1. What is the specified selector at here (in this example)?
2. Aside question. What happen when you set `waitUntilDone = YES`. I tried but I did not see any difference at all.

Comment: Please reformat your question to correctly use mini-Markdown, SO's formatting syntax.

Answer (score 0):

1) makeMyProgressBarMoving is your selector. 
2) you would only use the onMainThread version if you try to perform a selector on the main thread from within another thread. The documentation says:

Wait: A boolen that specifies whether E current thread blocks Until after the specified selector Is performed on the receiver on the main thread.